# Osm2pgsql error when importing planet into Database

Tags: database, postgresql

I have opened and imported planet into the database just a month ago but there was a problem with the version of planet I downloaded and had to delete it. Now I have downloaded another version of planet and I am getting the following error when I try to import it into the postgresql database.

The command I used to import the file into the database is

```
 osm2pgsql --slim -d gis -W -C 1500 --number-porcessess 3 ~/src/planet/planet.osm.pbf
```

Then I get this error and I am in the planet directory. I followed the instructions from http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/ to set this server up.

```
 Reading file : /planet-latest.osm.pbf Unable to open /planet-latest.osm.pbf 
 Error occured,cleaning up.
```

Has anyone else had this problem. All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If osm2pgsql can't open the pbf file, then you don't have a database problem, you have a osm2pgsql problem.  It looks like the name of the file reported to you is not the same as the name of the file you put on your command line, perhaps that is a clue to the problem.